# Replace a subset of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with some error

```
T item   V1   V2
1 a      2     .1
2 a      5     .8
1 b      1     .7
2 b      2     .2
```

I have another data frame with corrections for items concerning V1 only

```
T item   V1
1 a       2
2 a       6
```

How do I get the final data frame? Should I use merge or rbind. Note: actual data frames are big.

Comment: @akrun same as the first one except 6 instead of 5  in T-2, item-a

Comment: ok thanks, then the solution I provided should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be a data.table join `on` the 'T', 'item' and assigning the 'V1' with the the corresponding 'V1' column (`i.V1`) from the second dataset

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, V1 := i.V1, on = .(T, item)]
df1
#   T item V1  V2
#1: 1    a  2 0.1
#2: 2    a  6 0.8
#3: 1    b  1 0.7
#4: 2    b  2 0.2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(T = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), item = c("a", "a", "b", 
"b"), V1 = c(2L, 5L, 1L, 2L), V2 = c(0.1, 0.8, 0.7, 0.2)), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))


df2 <- structure(list(T = 1:2, item = c("a", "a"), V1 = c(2L, 6L)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: What if I have corrections for more than one column?

Comment: @PolarBear  Then you can do `setDT(df1)[df2, c("V1", "V2") := .(i.V1, i.V2), on = .(T, item)]`  If there are more than 10 columns or so `nm1 <- names(df1)[3:10]; seDT(df1)[df2, (nm1) := mget(paste0("i".nm1)), on = .(T, item)]`

Comment: thank you. At the moment I can't run the code. Will check and accept in the morning.

Comment: @PolarBear  Sure, no worries.

Comment: it seems to cycle if the cloumns are not of equal length. how to stop it and have NAs in place of cycled data?

Comment: @PolarBear  Not clear, do you have duplicates in both datasets

Comment: for a particular item both DFs have missing values, but it is mysteriously filled up in the final DF after using the proposed code

Comment: @PolarBear Do you mean missing values in the grouping columns

Comment: No not in the that but there are some missing values in v1

Comment: @PolarBear  If you can update your post with a new example and expected, it would be easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("T", "item")) %>%
  mutate(
    V1 = coalesce(as.numeric(V1.y), as.numeric(V1.x))
  ) %>%
  select(-V1.x, -V1.y)
```